# mongodb EmbedMany strategy=set

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, odm

I had a collection with an embedMany attribute using strategy=set, so an ArrayCollection was stored. However we deleted some items from the array and now there are some documents with keys not sequential integers.

I need to solve this inconsistence, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator and query for all documents where your `embedManyField` is of type `object`. Once you have these documents, apply `array_values` to fields where array shall be stored and save them again. Also to avoid such situations in future you should change your collection's strategy to either `setArray` or `atomicSetArray`.